# Deleted the partition on a MacBook using the Terminal but now unable to create new partition

Tags: disk-utility, partition, diskutil

I deleted the partition container by using the Terminal. Now I'm unable to create a partition.

Photo of a System Recovery Terminal window showing the output of 'diskutil list':

[image: Photo of a System Recovery Terminal window showing the output of 'diskutil list']

How can I delete all the partitions and create a new partition?

Comment: I do not have an Apple Silicon Mac to test, but I think you could try `diskutil addPartition disk0s1 apfs "Macintosh HD" 0`.

Comment: Are you unable to erase and partition the device in Disk Utility?  What were you trying to achieve by deleting the container?